# Причина ошибки при использовании объединения

Tags: c++

Есть у меня объединение:

```
union A {       
   double d;
   char c[10];
};
```

И когда я хочу его использовать, то мне не позволяют сделать с типом char:
`A o = { "asd" }; A s = {12}; \\ Значение типа const char * нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа double`

Однако если я в объединении поменяю местами char и double, то никаких ошибок нет. Почему так?

Answer (score 1):

При инициализации `union`а инициализируется всегда только первое поле (а не совпадающее по типу с инициализатором).

Исключение - если явно указать имя желаемого поля, например `A o{.c = "blah"};`.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что первое поле `double d;` можно инициализировать только литералом `12`, а `char c[10];` можно инициализировать как литералом `"asd"` (4 `char`), так и `12` (1 char). А вообще стоит явно указывать, какое поле иницилизировать, тогда таких проблем не будет.

```
A o{ .c{"asd"} };
A s{ .d{12} };
```

Comment: То есть проблема в том, что поле double не может никак интерпретировать строку "asd", в то время как поле char может как и "asd", так и 12? И почему перемена местами полей не вызывает этой ошибки(использовать явное указывание мне нельзя)?

Comment: @BURNIY_OVASH Я же написал - если поле `char c[10];` будет первым, то и иницилизироваться оно будет успешно, раз для него подходят оба инициализатора. Если `double` будет первым, то для него подходит только один - вот вам и ошибка.